# List objects in rows with one editable field (Model formset)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a set of objects with these fields:

- id
- Name (charfield)
- Location (Charfield)
- Owner (ForeignKey (user))

I want to create a form set that lists these objects in rows like so

> id name location owner(dropdown)

I would prefer for the first 3 fields not to be input fields, and just be printed text, with only the 4th field (owner) being a dropdown field that the user can edit.

In ModelFormset the only way to do this seems to be to set the fields as read only, but they would still render out as disabled fields which isn't exactly what I need.

Any thoughts on this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the template for the form you can reference the value of the field directly like so:

```
{{ form.id.value }}
{{ form.name.value }}
{{ form.location.value }}
{{ form.owner }}
```

The owner field will be rendered as an input and the others will be rendered as the value.

Comment: This seems to work, i had tried using {{ form.name.data }} before which resulting in None being printed, the value attribute is printing values correctly. Thanks!

Comment: Though actually, thinking about this. This still leaves these fields open to being posted to the view - and if they were the formset.save function would attempt to save their values. As they aren't set as read only. Perhaps a combination of this and setting the widgets to read only is best.